Need Recommendations for a Solar Attic Fan Setup
We have a roof with steep slope facing east/west and want the attic fans to run all day long. It seems that all solar attic fans are built to be used with only one panel per fan. Placing the panel on the west side meant warmer conditions inside earlier in the day, and vice versa for a panel on the east side.
So instead, I'd like to buy electric attic fans that could plug into a battery charged by two small solar panels, each one placed on either side of the roof. Any recommendations would help. Any battery that could be charged by two solar panels, any cable adapters required, and any panels that could charge the batteries while the fans are in use. The attic fans are likely going to be 120w gable fans on opposite ends of the roof. I was thinking each would have their own set of panels and battery.
Thank you all for any help you can provide.

Trivial solution with "solar attic fans" - buy them in pairs, alternate which side of the roof the panel goes on. Or mount both panels on the South gable end (since the roof slopes East West, presumably there's a North gable end and a South gable end.) Unless you are in the Southern Hemisphere, then choose the North gable end.
Otherwise just a bone stock two-string PWM or MPPT charge controller with low battery cutout for the attached load (Fans) (smaller ones tend to have these, larger ones don't. Beware cheap unlisted import crap from ebay/alibaba/amazon.)
Pick a voltage, get a battery, get DC fans to match. If you pay attention to getting the aforementioned low battery cutout for the attached load you won't need much of a battery, unless you want the fans running a long time after sundown, which a pure solar fan won't. Do remember to build your system with fuses (or DC-rated breakers) and other safe practices.
More than likely you could just bodge a second panel onto a solar fan with a couple of additional diodes to achieve your aim, but without knowing details it's hard to be certain that won't toast something.

Would a portable power station / solar generator replace the need for an MPPT charge controller? My current thought is to connect two 100W solar panels with an MC4 combiner into one portable power station and plug the 120W fan into the PPS's outlet. With a 200W PPS that provides at least 2,880Wh storage, I believe this set up will provide the charge needed to power the fan for 24 hours.

...but the sun does not shine on the roof for 24 hours (and if it does, no battery needed) so there's no need to run the fan 24 hours, much less 24 hours from batteries. As for using an inverter and 120V fans, there's needless inefficiencies in going through that conversion which a DC fan avoids. It's also going to cost more, or else be junk from alibaba or temu that probably burns your house down...

The idea was that using a portable power station / solar generator would simplify the process. Honest question: Is it really so dangerous to use this method? Is it that different from consistently running a desktop computer that is plugged into an uninterruptible power supply / battery backup?

Not if you buy a good one, listed by UL or ETL (or cUL in Canada, or TUV in Germany, etc.) it's the cheap unlisted stuff that burns down the house. And you'll be wasting a considerable abount of power on inefficiency - but if you have money to spend and this is how you want to spend it, sure, you can do that - but then you're a hop, skip and a jump from use mains power for the fans, and put up a grid-connected solar system to offset the use as a better use of the money. It will need to be true-sinewave to run 120V fan motors without kiling them.

Thank you very much for your responses. You've been very helpful. I've also been looking at the option of a grid-connected solar system, but recoiled at the pricing. It seemed like solar generator option would run at less than $500 per full set (panels, fan, cables, PPS) whereas the grid-connected idea looked to be several thousand. I'm very new to this and there has been a lot of contradicting information to sort through.
